# Tkinter shrink window to fit frame in the same way it expands?

Tags: python, tkinter

Edit: I found a fix! grid_forget() the frame you're coming from and grid the frame you're going to. Use try/except so when the program launches it doesn't fail instantly.

Here's the code for that fix:

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    try:
        self.frame.grid_forget()
    except:
        print("Frame not found")
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.frame = frame
```

Original post:

I'm using [this approach](https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/) to handle frames and switch between them.

I have multiple frames that I switch between, when switching frames I want the window to resize to fit as they [looked like this before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvD94.png)

I iterate through the the grid to resize the elements when the frame changes and the result [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avfxy.png)

[I mocked up the final result I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21cFQ.png)

Any help would be fantastic!

Here's the code for resizing the grid to fit the elements in the frame

```
    for i in range(frame.grid_size()[0]):
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, minsize=0, weight=0)

    for j in range(frame.grid_size()[1]):
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(j, minsize=0, weight=0)
```

And here's an assortment of things I've tried (uncommented them all)

```
    self.update_idletasks()
    self.update()
    self.minsize(width=0, height=0)

    self.geometry((str(frame.winfo_width()) + 'x' + str(frame.winfo_height())))
    self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, shrink=True)
    self.resizable(0, 0)
    frame.pack_propagate(0)
    self.pack_propagate(0)
    self.container.pack_forget()
    self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Here's the whole code for the frame change

```
class frameLauncher(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container = container
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # container.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        # container.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        # container.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        # container.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (mainWindow,
                  modifyEventWindow,
                  oneOffEventModifierWindow,
                  repeatableEventModificationWindow,
                  cycleEventModificationWindow,
                  settingsWindow):
            page_name = F.__name__

            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("mainWindow", None)

    def show_frame(self, page_name, event):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''

        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        editorList = ["oneOffEventModifierWindow", "repeatableEventModificationWindow", "cycleEventModificationWindow"]
        if page_name in editorList:
            frame.loadEvent(event)
        for i in range(frame.grid_size()[0]):
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, minsize=0, weight=0)
        for j in range(frame.grid_size()[1]):
            frame.grid_rowconfigure(j, minsize=0, weight=0)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        frame.blankFrame()  #Deletes the elements in the frame to reload
        frame.tkraise()
```

Answer (score 0):

Iff you are packing/griding all widgets on different `Frame` objects and switching between them, then do the following:

```
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
```

Then you just need to `raise` or `re-grid` any `Frame` object in the `grid space (0, 0)` of the `root` window

Comment: Thanks for the reply

This didn't fix it though. Like in the tutorial I linked there's a frame called "container" where all the frames sit in 0,0. I tried to configure the rows and columns of root and this container, neither worked. I'll add the whole code to the original post.